# How can I get some of the metallic (gold) colors on a piece of paper?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

I want to receive such an effect as on angel wings.
[image]

Comment: Basic scenario is to use BW image (for example wings stencil), which will serve as blending factor between paper and gold (white values for paper and black for gold or vice versa). Plug in this BW image (map) into "Mix shader" Fac, two other inputs will be gold and paper materials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just mix between two shaders. Turn your wings into a all black image to use as a mask as I have below.

***EDIT:***
This is a cleaner solution thanks to CEGATON:

[image]

[image]

These were the two images I used.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A few alternatives to this answer using only the princlpled shader: To keep the texture of the paper you can just plug the mask directly to the metalic input of the Principled Shader. By changing the rougness value you can make control the quality of the reflctive part https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLEHm.jpg. To add gold color to the "gold" part of the paper use an RBG mix node using the mask. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgVvU.png

Comment: it is an alternative, I just wanted to keep the texture of the paper.

Comment: I love you man!